# Always same content in WebView. How to set cache preferences?

Tags: ios, caching, webview

I have an iOS app with a WebView. But when I change something on my website, it often doesn't change in the WebView. I think this is because of  the cache. How should I set the cache preferences? Cache should be enable but there should always be the actually content. How can I solve this problem? Clear cache at start/end? After a special time (e.g. 5 minutes). Does anybody have an advice for me?
Thanks,
David.

Here is my code in ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender; {

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebsite.com"]; NSURLRequest * requestURL=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; [_site loadRequest:requestURL];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the cache :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender; {
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebsite.com"];
    NSURLRequest * requestURL=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [_site loadRequest:requestURL];
}
```

If you want to use the cache only when there is no modification, you need to add the `If-Modified-Since` header to your request. This is well explained [here](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where exactly to add? What does it do exactly?

Comment: I updated my post using your code, here we set the cache policy to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` that specifies that the connection should load the request without checking the cache

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it. Does it work with or without cache?

Comment: What do you mean ? This request will never use the cache.

Comment: I understand it so, too. But it would be better, if cache isn't totally disabled. (look at my question post)